# Could not find gem on the test (and possibly in the stage & prod) branch after removing from the master branch

Tags: ruby, git, chef-infra

i removed the gem "auto_tagger" from the Gemfile in a project. Everything looks to be working on the master/dev branch. i merged the branch to the test using a script. now i am getting this error

```
Switched to branch 'test'
/opt/mount1/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:357:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'auto_tagger (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

when the below script is called (this is not the full script, but it shows where it failed)

```
 def chef_refresh(root_dir = nil, environment = 'staging', branch)
        dir_prefix = root_dir.nil? ? nil : File.join(root_dir, '/')
        check_environment(environment)
        puts "Checking out #{branch} inside the something_chef_repo projects."
        system("git checkout #{branch}")
        check_branch(environment, branch)
        puts "git pull something_chef_repo"
        system("git pull") || raise("unable to complete git pull for gemini_chef_repo")
        puts "running bundle"
        system("bundle")
        puts "running berks"
        system("berks install")
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove a gem that is obviously in use by your application? Is the question about how to remove it completely or how to make it work again?

Comment: This gem **must be** referenced in the `Gemfile` of your current working directory (the 'test' branch).
If you are not using that gem, update the `Gemfile` appropriately.
If you need the gem (as I suspect) use `bundle install` to get it back.

Comment: The gem is not required anymore. And i am trying to remove it completely. In our enviroment, we use jenkins to merges the branches from the master to test to stage and prod. After every merge process, the script is ran to perform a chef-refresh. During the chef-refresh script the thing bombs out.

Comment: When i removed the gem from the gemfile of the master/dev branch and merge the branch to the test, did it had not updated the gemfile on the test branch?

Answer (score 0):

It turn out that the gem auto-tagger was still required by the chef-refresh script. I had to re-add the gem and bundle install on the master/dev branch, before i merge it into the other branches. Thanks spickermann and Thom Parkin